# Vagrant ERROR 2002 (HY000)

Tags: mysql, vagrant

I'm running scotchbox on vagrant, and this is the second time i've had this issue. Mysql just stops running. The only thing that seems to fix it is if I re import the box and lose all my databases. I tried adding swap memory to the machine but that did not solve the issue. Reboot does not help. When i try to start mysql, it says job failed.

I don't want to lose all my databases again. Please help me find the solution!

ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock'

Comment: Probably you should invest some time to setup your own dev-box?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting "Can't connect...through socket '/tmp/mysql'" when installing MySQL on Mac OS X 10.6 with Homebrew](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4788381/getting-cant-connect-through-socket-tmp-mysql-when-installing-mysql-on-m)

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the issue. Large mysql log files was the problem.

sudo service mysql stop
  sudo rm /var/lib/mysql/ib_logfile0
  sudo rm /var/lib/mysql/ib_logfile1